# How to use sinon-test with TypeScript

Tags: unit-testing, typescript, testing, mocha.js, sinon

I want to use sinon-test to clean up my tests after using sinon stubs. But I get errors...

**How can I fix this?**

> sinonTest.configureTest is deprecated and will be removed from the
>   public API in a future version of sinon-test
>   /Users/olejensen/WebstormProjects/SAM-api/node_modules/sinon-test/lib/test.js:67
>           throw new TypeError("expected sinon object");
>           ^
>
> TypeError: expected sinon object
>       at Object.configure (/Users/olejensen/WebstormProjects/SAM-api/node_modules/sinon-test/lib/test.js:67:15)
>       at Function.sinonTest.configureTest (/Users/olejensen/WebstormProjects/SAM-api/node_modules/sinon-test/lib/index.js:18:17)
>       at Object. (/Users/olejensen/WebstormProjects/SAM-api/test/unit/contract-provider/contracts-routes.spec.js:15:24)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
>       at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
>       at /Users/olejensen/WebstormProjects/SAM-api/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:230:27
>       at Array.forEach (native)
>       at Mocha.loadFiles (/Users/olejensen/WebstormProjects/SAM-api/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:227:14)
>       at Mocha.run (/Users/olejensen/WebstormProjects/SAM-api/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:513:10)
>       at Object. (/Users/olejensen/WebstormProjects/SAM-api/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha:480:18)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
>       at startup (bootstrap_node.js:158:16)
>       at bootstrap_node.js:575:3

**contract.spec.ts**

```
import * as chai from "chai";
import chaiDateTime = require('chai-datetime');
import * as sinon from "sinon";
import * as sinonTest from 'sinon-test';
import {ContractOption} from "../../../src/entity/ContractOption";
import {sumOptionsTotalPrice} from "../../../src/contract-provider/contracts-routes";

chai.use(chaiDateTime);
const expect = chai.expect;
const test = sinonTest.configureTest(sinon);

describe('Contracts-routes', function() {

    describe("sumOptionsTotalPrice()", function() {

        it("should return correct price with 2 options", test(function() {
            // arrange
            const opt1 = <any> sinon.createStubInstance(ContractOption);
            opt1.price = 10;
            const opt2 = <any> sinon.createStubInstance(ContractOption);
            opt2.price = 20;
            const options: ContractOption[] = [opt1, opt2];

            // act
            const actual = sumOptionsTotalPrice(options)
            const expected = 30;

            // assert
            expect(actual).to.equal(expected)
        }));
    });
});
```

**package.json**

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/bcrypt": "^1.0.0",
    "@types/body-parser": "^1.16.0",
    "@types/chai": "^4.0.1",
    "@types/chai-datetime": "0.0.30",
    "@types/chai-spies": "0.0.0",
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.0",
    "@types/csv-parse": "^1.1.7",
    "@types/csv-stringify": "^1.4.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.0.35",
    "@types/express-jwt": "0.0.34",
    "@types/html-pdf": "^2.1.2",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^7.2.0",
    "@types/mocha": "^2.2.41",
    "@types/node": "^8.0.12",
    "@types/postmark": "^1.3.0",
    "@types/sinon": "^2.3.3",
    "@types/sinon-test": "^1.0.2",
    "@types/stripe-node": "^4.6.7",
    "chai": "^4.1.0",
    "chai-datetime": "^1.5.0",
    "chai-spies": "git+https://github.com/chaijs/chai-spies.git#master",
    "mocha": "^3.4.2",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.9",
    "sinon": "^3.0.0",
    "sinon-test": "^2.0.0",
    "swagger-parser": "^3.4.1",
    "swagger2-ts-codegen": "2.5.0",
    "tap-spec": "^4.1.1",
    "typescript": "2.3.4",
    "typings": "^2.1.1",
    "walk-sync": "^0.3.1"
  }
```

Comment: `sinon-test@2` isn't compatible with `sinon@3` (yet).

Comment: I wish they would document this some where...

Comment: how are you running the above test-case using `mocha` or `ts-node` provide us a more info